# jtable java. Сортировка с сохранением номеров строк

Tags: java, сортировка, jtable

при включении table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
после сортировки визуализация отличается от содержания таблицы.

На примере:
1.Открыли таблицу.
2.нажали на столбец(отсортировали)
3.выбрали строку selectedRow
4. (String) table_1.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRow, 0) получили значение не то, которое выбрали, а то которое было в строке selectedRow до сортировки.

Как то можно "переписать" модель после сортировки, чтоб выбиралось то, что я действительно выбираю.?

Comment: Добавьте ваш код.

Comment: selectedRow=table_1_1.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать метод [JTable.convertRowIndexToModel(int viewRowIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel-int-)

Comment: Примного благодарен. помогло.

Comment: после сортировки теперь перестало работать отслеживание изменений в таблице,видимо, надо как то переиндектисровать и тут                         //для отслеживания изменений
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        int row = e.getFirstRow();
      //  row=table_1_1.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
   int column = e.getColumn();

   TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
 if (( column != 14) &&(row < model.getRowCount())) 
 { 
  
   model.setValueAt(true,row, 14); //это не пашет
  }

    }

Comment: теперь весь код наперекосяк.  надо было просто сортировать массив, а  не таблицу

Answer (score 0):

Была та же проблема, исправил таким образом:

```
//было:
int row = table.rowAtPoint(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
//сделал:
int row = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.rowAtPoint(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY())));
```